# while connecting to SFTP server getting error : Syntax error at line 5 : `<' is not matched

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, sftp

I am trying to connect SFTP server I am getting error: Syntax error at line 5 : `<' is not matched. I am using ksh.

```
while [ $counter -gt 0 ]; do 
    sftp user@host <<-EOF
       ls -ltr
    EOF
    counter=$(($counter-1))
done
```

But it works for below.

```
while [ $counter -gt 0 ]; do 
    sftp user@host
       ls -ltr
    EOF
    counter=$(($counter-1))
done
```

Comment: `<<-EOF` only works if you use tabs, not spaces. It's better to just use `<<EOF` and dedent the closing `EOF`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, the `-` in `<<-EOF` tells it to ignore leading tabs. However, folks copying-and-pasting code following that often end up with non-tab whitespace, hence...

Comment: It absolutely does matter, insofar as it means there exists a circumstance where the `EOF` would still be recognized as closing the heredoc when *not* at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Is it good practice to rely on that? No, not at all. Is it legal, so the OP could have copied code that really did work (and then changed the whitespace type by mistake, or used an editor configured to do that implicitly, thus breaking it)? Yes.

Comment: You are right!. Copy from text editor didn't worked. It worked after typing it. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Glad to hear that helped! Since we've locked down the problem, I closed it with a link to another instance (the other one is written up for bash rather than ksh, but they're fully compatible as to this syntax, and the answers written there are entirely applicable).